# websocket handshake request using C#

Tags: c#, websocket, client

I am writing a websocket client using C#. But I can't figure out how to send the websocket handshake request to the server in C# and how to generate sec-websocket-key.

Answer (score 0):

The client request sample will be like below.

```
GET /chat HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:8000
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

Server response sample would be like below.

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
```

Look at the [sample websocket server code from mozilla.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server)

To generate the key on client side you can use random generators.

```
String secWebSocketKey = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("WebSocket rocks!"));
```